# can I perform local fftw with mpi?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fftw

I am using fftw3 library to perform mutli_dimensional (2D let's say but it could also be 3d) dft on my data with Fortran. (I have a fortran interface to use fftw correctly with fortran).
It's about solving electromagnetics equations with some numerical algorithms. So my array represents a 2D (or 3D) electromagnetic component and the EM field in space.
My data is stored locally in different MPI-processes. Since Fortran is column major my data is expected to be in colummn major order (thus my domain decomposition needs to be done only throughout the last dimension, which I try to change)

Let's say I have a 2D array(x,y) with 8 mpi tasks.
fftw_mpi currently expects my array to be decomposed through y direction only).
I want to be able to perform an x - direction split to perform a local dft on the upper and lower part (through x direction) of my data.
I thought about bringing together 4 mpi tasks to execute two fftw_mpi_plan, one in each half subarray.

Comment: You may be interested by [P3DFFT](http://www.p3dfft.net/user-guide), a GPLv3 DFT library which implements such a 2D decomposition. Otherwise, if you only want to perform the local DFT on local data without communications between processes, each procress can call FFTW the usual way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But  I want to perform a local dft with multiple mpi processess for each dft

Comment: Have you considered transpose your data using something like MPI_ALLTOALL and then apply serial FFTW on your data in local memory? Alltoall is designed for this sort of situation.